# SPWM, CPWM, and DPWM: what are they?

Tags: pwm

What are SPWM, CPWM, and DPWM?

I googled, and they are single PWM, combined PWM, and PWM is pulse-width-modulation, which I already know.

DPWM I am not sure. I don't know it is dual PWM or dual-phase PWM.

But, these is all I know. So far I cannot know what they really are. Web search result is vague. May these terms are too easy or rarely used, so I find it difficult to get a clear explanation on website. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Where did you see these? These might just be arbitrary names used by datasheet authors. CPWM could be either complimentary PWM or center aligned PWM. It's all up in the air.

Comment: I  saw CPWM & DPWM in a slide, but without context, so it is really confusing. Also, wiki says SPWM stands for Sine–triangle pulse width modulation, which I still don't know what it is.

Comment: Then ignore those acronyms since they could mean anything. How about asking what the specific full name of different types of PWM? That would actually be answerable.

Comment: Don't know CPWM but SPWM and DPWM are likely to be Single (sided) and Double (sided) PWM. In single sided, only the falling (usually, or rising) edge moves around as the duty cycle changes; in DPWM, both rising and falling edges move. Generate with a sawtooth or a triangle wave respectively. Note that SPWM adds a phase shift as duty cycle changes, DPWM does not, offering lower distortion where that matters.